New crack in basement wall
We've been in our house since last December, so coming up on a year. There were two cracks on this same wall that had been repaired. Today while I was down there, I notched this new crack that just appeared. We're going to get someone out here asap to look at it, but I thought I'd ask here if anyone has had experience with something like this. It's concerning (to me at least) that the new crack is on the same wall as the repairs. First picture is of the repairs and the second one is of the new crack, which is to the right of the old ones.


I had some cracks like these in a 1994 build.  Not sure how common they are.  In my case it was where the footing had been chipped away for a 4" perimeter drain to exit from a crawl to the outside.  I suppose that part of the wall must have settled more or it was chipped out while the concrete wasn't cured and the crack developed while it was weak.  Typically you don't know you have this kind of crack until you see a leak inside as the wall are furred out with wood and then drywalled.  How were the previous cracks repaired?

They were repaired with epoxy by the previous owner about a year and a half before we bought the house. I'm most concerned because this new crack is new so it makes me thing something is going on with that tall for there to be a new crack.

Any change in the local weather?  Extra long dry or wet spells?

We're in eastern Missouri, and it's been pretty hot, not alot of rain. Then a week of really nice weather back to hot temps.
